# Horizontally Distribute Inner-Divs of 3-Column Container Without Using Percentages? - Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm wondering if there's a better way to evenly space the three divs within a parent div (horizontally) using flex. Here's what I have:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.left-div, .middle-div, .right-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 33.3%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-div">
            Left
        </div>
        <div class="middle-div">
            Middle
        </div>
        <div class="right-div">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I set each child-div / column to `width: 33.3%` - is there a CSS property that will automatically force them to span 100% width of their parent, collectively, without using percentages?

If I get rid of `width: 33%`, I get this:

```css
.container {
        display: flex;
}
.left-div, .middle-div, .right-div {
        display: flex; 
        justify-content: center;
        /*width: 33.3%;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-div">
            Left
        </div>
        <div class="middle-div">
            Middle
        </div>
        <div class="right-div">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried setting the parent div to `justify-content: space-between;`, but this is now forcing the content of the inner divs to get aligned to the left (for the left div) or to the right (for the right div):

```css
.container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
}
.left-div, .middle-div, .right-div {
        display: flex; 
        justify-content: center;
        /*width: 33.3%;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-div">
            Left
        </div>
        <div class="middle-div">
            Middle
        </div>
        <div class="right-div">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that setting each child div to `width: 33%` works, but is there a better way? Without having to calculate percentages if I wanted 7 columns, for example?

Comment: flex-grow:1; should stretch them evenly without a width. padding and margin won't also be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just try with `justify-content: space-around;`

As a plus, I'd recommend you have a look at [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a lot of interesting flexbox explanations :)

```css
.container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
}
.left-div, .middle-div, .right-div {
        display: flex; 
        justify-content: center;
        /*width: 33.3%;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-div">
            Left
        </div>
        <div class="middle-div">
            Middle
        </div>
        <div class="right-div">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting and it looks like `justify-content: space-evenly` is working also - thanks!

Comment: They're similar, yes. The linked guide quotes: `space-around`: items are evenly distributed in the line with equal space around them. Note that visually the spaces aren’t equal, since all the items have equal space on both sides. The first item will have one unit of space against the container edge, but two units of space between the next item because that next item has its own spacing that applies.
`space-evenly`: items are distributed so that the spacing between any two items (and the space to the edges) is equal.

Answer (score 1):

[`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) might be what you need here .

> The `flex-grow` CSS property sets the flex grow factor of a flex item main size. It specifies how much of the remaining space in the flex container should be assigned to the item (the flex grow factor).

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.left-div, .middle-div, .right-div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-div">
            Left
        </div>
        <div class="middle-div">
            Middle
        </div>
        <div class="right-div">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```